# Python - Check if signature annotation is of specific class

Tags: python, annotations

When using

```
for sig in inspect.signature.parameters.items():
    if isinstance(sig[1].annotation, inspect._empty):
        print("empty")
```

I never get the console to say print "empty". Even though when using

```
print(sig[1].annotation)
```

before the if clause gives me the output: `<class 'inspect._empty'>`.
I also tried using string comparison like this:

```
if sig[1].annotation == "<class 'inspect._empty'>":
    print("empty")
```

Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `isinstance`, just check `is inspect._empty`, i.e:

```
for sig in inspect.signature.parameters.items():
    if sig[1].annotation is inspect._empty:
        print("empty")
```

or preferably use the documented `Signature.empty` or `Parameter.empty`. They're all the same, but try to avoid protected attributes, i.e. those starting with `_`.

Comment: xxx is Signature.empty was exactly what I was looking for thanks.